# Can't manage to open TensorFlow SavedModel for usage in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm kinda new to TensorFlow and Keras, so please excuse any accidental stupidity, but I have an issue. I've been trying to load in models from the [TensorFlow Detection Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), but haven't had much success.

I can't figure out how to read these saved_model folders (they contain a saved_model.pb file, and an assets and variables folder), so that they're accepted by Keras. Nor can I figure out a way to convert these models so that they may be loaded in. I've tried converting the SavedModel to ONNX, and then convert the ONNX-model to Keras, but that didn't work. Trying to load the original model as a saved_model, and then trying to to save this loaded model in another format gave me no success either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to Tensorflow (and I guess deep learning) I would suggest you stick with the API because the detection zoo models best interface with the object detection API. If you have already downloaded the model, you just need to export it using the exporter_main_v2.py script. This article explains it very well [link](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_object_detection_saved_model.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-object-detection-saved-model-py).

Comment: I was looking into that guide myself as well, but as far as I can tell, the saved_model module does not provide the option to train a model. I'd like to be able to further train a pre-trained model on my own dataset, which is why I was looking for a way to convert it to Keras, so that I may train the model.

Comment: You need to set the finetune parameter. Read this section of the article: [link](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#download-pre-trained-model) If this helps please accept the answer :)